# DRF ApiTest runs on old code, doesn't update

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, web-api-testing

Running ApiTest in a Django-REST application. After correcting something and running tests, they show old errors.

I'm running the app with docker-compose. Previously deleting the database volume helped (idk why) but now it's simply running old code every time.
I've also tried making another clone of the project and it runs tests properly. I wonder if it's some kind of cache but I'm not even sure where to look for it.

In an example below: I've moved a class method to signal but it's still running an old version in test.

[image: DRF ApiTest runs on old code, doesn't update1]

**UPDATE:**
It appears the reason is in Redis container. How do I turn off caching
persistency on local?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because noone but myself was involved and it's not helping anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out that I was running a wrong command. Instead of this:

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.stage.yml run --rm app make test`

I had to run this:

`docker-compose exec app make test`

Hope it helps someone. If someone can give a more informative description, that'd be great.